# Resolving dependencies automatically in .NET Core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

Does built-in Dependency Injection framework in .NET Core 2.2 **not** resolve dependency and inject the instance automatically when an instance is created? Or only way to inject dependency is by resolving it explicitly while creating new instance?

I am building a class library project (So, [FromServices] attribute is not an option to me) where it seems to me that I will have to pass the IServiceProvider almost in every class's constructor.

Have I misunderstood something?

Note: Code snippet is just illustrative.

```
public class A
{
    public A()
    {

    }

    public void DoSomethingWithB()
    {
        var b = new B(// To resolve IConfiguration here, I need IServiceProvider. That means I will need to inject IServiceProvider in class A first. Will it go on nesting like this everywhere?);
    }
}

public class B
{
    private IConfiguration _config;
    public B(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }
    public void DoWork()
    {
        // Use _config here.
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're building a class library, then the consumers of the library are responsible for passing in the objects it requires in the constructor. That may be the DI framework. Note that good practice suggest `B` does not rely on `IConfiguration` and instead is an interface that allows the consumer to supply the correct values, by also passing in an instance of it to the constructor for `A`

Comment: Maybe you don't need to manually create `B` and simply accepts `B` object in `A` constructor? You're trying to use [Service Locator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern), which is really an anti-pattern.

Comment: @DavidG: Yes, but as I see IServiceProvider will appear at too many places. How about .NET Core DI itself giving me an instance because the dependency is clearly stated and the DI mapping is constructed right at startup? Or this pattern is not supported in .NET Core?

Comment: Why do you need `IServiceProvider` all over the place? Let DI create your instance of `A` by registering it with the DI framework, also register `B`.

Comment: @YuriiN. Is it not that I am forced to use service locator by Microsoft?

Comment: @Learner absolutely not, you can always use constructor injection if you want.

Comment: @YuriiN. I am already declaring dependencies in constructor. But don't I need `IServiceProvider` in class A because I need to get instance of `IConfiguration` in `DoSomethingWithB` method? I have to get instance of `IConfiguration` myself and pass it to B's constructor. Is it not a Service Locator then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should register service `B` in the service provider in the `ConfigureServices` method. Then you can inject service `B` into service `A` using regular constructor injection. For example:

```cs
public void ConfigureService(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<B>();

    // Other stuff..
}

public class A
{
    private readonly B _b;

    public A(B b)
    {
        _b = b;
    }

    // Use service B in your methods...
}

public class B
{
    private IConfiguration _config;

    public B(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }
}
```

You can create deeper nested levels if you want. For instance you can add service `A` to the dependency container as well (using `services.AddSingleton<A>`()) and then inject service  `A` (which will automatically inject service `B`, etc, etc) into another service or a controller.

Answer (score 3):

Your class library project should not know anything about dependency injection at all. What you should do instead is to ensure that every class accepts all of its dependencies in constructor like this:

```
public void MyClass(IMyDependency dependency)
```

It is work for something that is called `Composition Root` to ensure that everything gets resolved from the top. E.g. in case of ASP.NET it will be the framework itself that will call `Resolve` to get the `Controller` and compose the whole tree of objects where your class will be a direct or indirect dependency to the controller.

This principle has a fancy name of "Hollywood principle": don't call us, we call you. If you will resolve the dependency yourself (i.e. "call them"), then you are doing something that is calls `Service Locator` that is considered an antipattern. So instead you are relying that someone (i.e. "they call you") will inject a right dependency in your class at some initial point of entry.

Additionally any design of a class library that is aware of DI container will lead to many problems in the future when you want to e.g. do unit testing, change DI container, etc. So your best bet is to not know anything about container in there.

P.S. Microsoft itself has actually made a mistake in my eyes when they bundled a lot of libraries with the DI container (`IServiceCollection`). E.g. logging libraries, HTTP factory, etc. all rely on this DI container to do the job, making it near impossible to switch to another one.

I understand that this will make it so much easier for someone to use it without understanding DI too well, but in the long run it does limit you and make e.g. unit testing mor cumbersome.